# PHP on EC2 is just printing out my PHP file and not executing

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have this as my index.php on a basic EC2 instance.

```
<?php
$conn =  new mysqli('localhost', 'testdb_user', 'testpass', 'testdb', '');
$result = $conn->query("SELECT message FROM test");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['message'];
?>
```

When I visit my public DNS I get this:

```
query("SELECT message FROM test"); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); echo $row['message']; ?>
```

printed to the browser.

I've installed php and the table in mysql is fine (i have repleaced db name etc with my actual credentials.

Answer (score 4):

You have either installed PHP incorrectly or failed to restart your web server after installing it. If it's apache, try this:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

It doesn't have anything to do with your mysql config - php is not trying to execute the script at all.

Comment: And also make sure Apache is actually configured to use php

Comment: That's what I was hinting at with 'installed php correctly'. Depending on PHP version and webserver version, you should have a `LoadModule` line somewhere and something like `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in your config file

Comment: i just did a yum install httpd do i always have to configure the server to run php or is there a different way to install apache that comes preconfigured with php?... if not how can i find the exact way to enable php?

Comment: did you try restarting the server after installing php? did you try installing php after installing httpd?

Answer (score 0):

In my case PHP cli was working on ec2 ubuntu instance and as you said browser just prints source code instead of executing it

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php php
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I have run from 3rd line (install php) and that fixed my issue

Ref: http://fredericpaladin.com/kb/aws-ec2-instance-with-ubuntu-apache2-web-server/